# Remote cocreate call "Class not registered"

Tags: vb.net

I have read everything I can find on the net about "class not registered".

I have a vb Com dll which I have installed on the server. 
(I did not write the DLL an don't have the source) The server is 64 bit

I have a 32 bit program (Delphi7) on a 64 bit machine.

The program does a cocreate with the server name and gets a "class not registered".

If I put the program on the server and run a cocreate it works, the class is registered.

In desperation I did an install of the DLL on the local PC and the cocreate works

I checked the registration on both machines, it is identical, and the registry 
HKEY_Classes_root_wow6432Node\CLSID\ on both machines has the registration GUID.
The setup/registration process on each machine being identical.

Why does it create when the call is local (on both machines) and not when the call is remote?

It would seem that the remote call from PC to server even though from a 32 bit program is being seen by the server as a 64 bit call.

Note: the server is a virtual server, does this make a difference?

Any help much appreciated.

The server has a program called Pastel Partner which uses Pervasive Btrieve
The VB6 DLL (and associated DLLs) are simply a separate program which can be accessed via the interface to provide certain functions like an input of an accounting entry into the Btrieve Files instead of typing it into the Pastel Program.

My program starts of course with a create of the interface, which seems to work if My program (32 bit) is run on the server as createobject(class), but not when it is run on a remote PC with the server name.Createobject(class,server) when the class not registered occurs.

It is the server which is a virtual server.

Answer (score 0):

Local and Remote are different. To access remotely, you have to grant access.
I didn't quite get your problem and I have no idea what server you are using so if this will help, click for details... https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mysql/remote-access/
or you can specify your search methods like how to remotely access "database" and whatnot.

If your problem is not really the remote access on your database then try this. This might be of help. http://www.theogray.com/blog/2009/10/comexception-regdbeclassnotreg-on-64-bit-windows

P.S. If you are using virtual machine, it is already considered like using a different PC.